# At what distance does the galactic tide significantly affect the orbit of a heliocentric object?

Tags: orbit, galactic-dynamics, trans-neptunian-object, 9th-planet

The title essentially explains the question. I was wondering if the galactic tide could play a role in raising perihelia of extreme trans-Neptunian objects (i.e. Sedna) versus the effect of a hypothetical Planet Nine.